# What is the best permission to apache htdocs on my linux?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, permissions, visual-studio-code, htdocs

I am using VSCode for my editor, but whenever I want to save the file, it always requires a password. I've searched for some of these related topics, there are some solutions I get that is giving full access to my code editor or changing folder permissions. I prefer to change permissions because giving root access to the code editor is more dangerous, but I am still confused because there are some permission options like using the 777 or 755 permissions, which one is the best fit for my case? I appreciate your answer.

Comment: The best is to make the files owned by you

Comment: [Take a look at this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)